# Updating Multiple Columns in sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter, sql-update

I am wanting to update multiple columns in my 'Class' Table in sqlite. I do not know how to do this so I approached the same syntax as an 'INSERT' query however, I seem to be having the following syntax error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error`

The line I am currently having issues is

```
e_sql= "UPDATE Class SET (ClassType,Location,UserID,Staff,Time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
c.execute(e_sql,(classes,location,r,staff,time))
```

I am just wondering how to create a query to update multiple columns in my 'Class' table. Here is my current code:

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as ms
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import datetime

global time 
time = datetime.datetime.now()

with sqlite3.connect('Gym.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,FirstName TEXT ,LastName TEXT ,Gender TEXT,Email TEXT NOT NULL,Phone TEXT NOT NULL,Username TEXT NOT NULL,Password TEXT NOT NULL);')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Staff (StaffID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Role TEXT NOT NULL, Name TEXT);')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Gym (GymID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Location TEXT);')
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Class (ClassID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ClassType TEXT, Location TEXT, UserID INTEGER, Staff TEXT, StaffID INTEGER, Time TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID), FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES Staff (StaffID));')
db.commit()
db.close()

class main:
    def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    self.variable_edit_class = StringVar()
    self.variable_edit_time = StringVar()
    self.variable_edit_location = StringVar()
    self.variable_edit_staff = StringVar()
    self.widgets()

def edit_sql(self):
    username = self.Username.get()
    password = self.Password.get()
    classes = self.variable_edit_class.get()
    location = self.variable_edit_location.get()
    time = self.variable_edit_time.get()
    staff = self.variable_staff.get()

    with sqlite3.connect('Gym.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Username = (?) AND Password =(?)', (str(username),str(password)))

    result = c.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        r = row[0]

    e_sql= "UPDATE Class SET (ClassType,Location,UserID,Staff,Time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
    c.execute(e_sql,(classes,location,r,staff,time))

def widgets(self):
self.editf = Frame(self.master, height=500,width=600)

        green_label_12 = Label(self.editf,text = "", font=('arial',15),fg='black',bg='light sea green',width=600,height=3)
        green_label_12.place(x=0,y=5)

        edit_class_label = Label(self.editf, text = "Class Bookings", font =('arial',15, 'bold'),fg = 'black',bg = 'light sea green')
        edit_class_label.place(x=220,y=20)

        back_btn11 = Button(self.editf, text ='Back', width = 5,bg = 'brown', command=self.dashboard)
        back_btn11.place(x=10,y=465)

        edit_classes_label = Label(self.editf, text = "Class", font =('arial',15),fg = 'black')
        edit_classes_label.place(x=25,y=110)

        edit_time_label = Label(self.editf, text = "Time", font =('arial',15),fg = 'black')
        edit_time_label.place(x=250,y=110)

        edit_location_label = Label(self.editf, text = "Location", font =('arial',15),fg = 'black')
        edit_location_label.place(x=25,y=200)

        edit_staff_label = Label(self.editf, text = "Staff", font =('arial',15),fg = 'black')
        edit_staff_label.place(x=260,y=200)

        Edit_Classes = [
            "Boxing",
            "Cardio",
            "Gym",
            "Strength",
            "Swim",
            "Yoga"
            ]


        self.variable_edit_class.set("Please Select")

        edit_booking_options = OptionMenu(self.editf,self.variable_edit_class,*Edit_Classes)
        edit_booking_options.place(x=90,y=110)

        Edit_Times = [
            "8:00 AM",
            "9:00 AM",
            "10:00 AM",
            "11:00 AM",
            "12:00 PM",
            "1:00 PM",
            "2:00 PM",
            "3:00 PM",
            "4:00 PM",
            "5:00 PM",
            "6:00 PM"
            ]

        self.variable_edit_time.set("Please Select")

        edit_time_options = OptionMenu(self.editf,self.variable_edit_time,*Edit_Times)
        edit_time_options.place(x=315,y=110)

        Edit_Location = [
            "Carrara",
            "Nerang",
            "Robina",
            "Helensvale"
            ]


        self.variable_edit_location.set("Please Select")

        edit_location_options = OptionMenu(self.editf,self.variable_edit_location,*Edit_Location)
        edit_location_options.place(x=115,y=200)

        Edit_Staff = [
            "Any",
            "John Cena",
            "Mike Tyson",
            "The Rock",
            "Terry Crews",
            "Mr George",
            "None"
            ]

        self.variable_edit_staff.set("Please Select")
        edit_staff_options = OptionMenu(self.editf,self.variable_edit_staff,*Edit_Staff)
        edit_staff_options.place(x=325,y=200)

        submit_btn_4 = Button(self.editf, text ='Update', width = 6,bg = 'dodger blue', command=self.edit_sql)
        submit_btn_4.place(x=535,y=470)


root = Tk()
root.title("Gym Membership System")
main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Provide a [mre].

Comment: Ok I just edited the post. Hopefully you can run it. Let me know if it doesnt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for an `UPDATE` statement is (for SQLite 3.15.0+):

```
UPDATE Class SET (ClassType,Location,UserID,Staff,Time) = (?,?,?,?,?)
```

or in standard SQL:

```
UPDATE Class SET 
  ClassType = ?,
  Location = ?, 
  UserID = ?,
  Staff = ?,
  Time = ?
```

but I think that you also need a WHERE clause, because this will update all the rows of the table.

Comment: Do I have below that query c.execute(e_sql,(classes,location,r,staff,time)) ?

Comment: The code in my answer should replace: `e_sql= "UPDATE Class SET (ClassType,Location,UserID,Staff,Time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"` with `e_sql= "UPDATE Class SET (ClassType,Location,UserID,Staff,Time) = (?,?,?,?,?)"`

Comment: If your version of SQLite is prior to 3.15.0 use the 2nd query.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` have different semantics. You write:

```
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
```

but:

```
UPDATE table SET col1=val1, col2=val2, col3=val3, ... [WHERE ...]
```

Any `val` can be replaced with a `?` to have a parameterized query, and `UPDATE` optionaly accepts a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Class VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",
                                 (classes,location,r,staff,time))
c.commit()
```